# Maven + Jitpack Dependency Missing Artifact

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jitpack

Having some trouble with a Maven project I'm making. I recently found a library I want to use distributed through Jitpack; I've never heard of it, but it seemed fairly simple to add a Maven dependency with it, so I followed the example to get a pom.xml like this:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jitpack.io</id>
        <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.IQSS</groupId>
        <artifactId>dataverse-client-java</artifactId>
        <version>dv14-12-compatible</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I've stripped out a lot, as everything else works just fine. Only when adding the above sections to the pom.xml does Eclipse complain that the artifact is missing. Here is the URL to the library I'd like to use: https://github.com/IQSS/dataverse-client-java

To my knowledge I've constructed the repository and dependency information correctly. Is on of them incorrect? Or have I neglect a step in adding this dependency? I have done nothing to the project except add the above entries to my pom.

Thanks!

Comment: That works for me in vscode. However, deliberately inserting a typo (e.g. compatiblez) reroduces your problem.